# Function closure performance

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, closures, implementation

I thought that I improve performance when I replace this code:

```
def f(a, b):
  return math.sqrt(a) * b
result = []
a = 100
for b in range(1000000):
  result.append(f(a, b))
```

with:

```
def g(a):
  def f(b):
    return math.sqrt(a) * b
  return f
result = []
a = 100
func = g(a)
for b in range(1000000):
  result.append(func(b))
```

I assumed that since `a` is fixed when the closure is performed, the interpreter would precompute everything that involves `a`, and so `math.sqrt(a)` would be repeated just once instead of 1000000 times.

Is my understanding always correct, or always incorrect, or correct/incorrect depending on the implementation?

I noticed that the code object for `func` is built (at least in CPython) before runtime, and is immutable. The code object then seems to use global environment to achieve the closure. This seems to suggest that the optimization I hoped for does not happen.

Comment: Actually that code won't run, you're calling `func` with only one argument, although it has 2 parameters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I assumed that since a is fixed when the closure is performed, the interpreter would precompute everything that involves a, and so
>   math.sqrt(a) would be repeated just once instead of 1000000 times.

That assumption is wrong, I don't know where it came from. A closure just captures variable bindings, in your case it captures the value of `a`, but that doesn't mean that any more magic is going on: The expression `math.sqrt(a)` is still evaluated every time `f` is called.

After all, it *has* to be computed every time because the interpreter doesn't know that `sqrt` is "pure" (the return value is only dependent on the argument and no side-effects are performed). Optimizations like the ones you expect are practical in functional languages (referential transparency and static typing help a lot here), but would be very hard to implement in Python, which is an imperative and dynamically typed language.

That said, if you want to precompute the value of `math.sqrt(a)`, you need to do that explicitly:

```
def g(a):
  s = math.sqrt(a)
  def f(b):
    return s * b
  return f
```

Or using `lambda`:

```
def g(a): 
  s = math.sqrt(a)
  return lambda b: s * b
```

Now that `g` really returns a function with 1 parameter, you have to call the result with only one argument.

Comment: The assumption was just my own thought: huh, something can clearly be optimized, so I guess it must be optimized.

Comment: CPython doesn't work that way. It's a thoroughly "pure" execution environment with no magic like that done.

Comment: @max: I added a paragraph on why such optimizations are not included (I won't say impossible) in CPython. Do you come from a functional background? Functional languages are more likely to be able to do such optimizations.

Comment: @aaronasterling: That's exactly what I mean. Python has no mechanisms to declare the purity of a function, let alone derive it this property from the context.

Comment: You can't tell anything about a Python program without running it. Best thing you can do is guess. Just imagine what setting `math.sqrt = lambda *args: input("Anything goes")` *anywhere* would do to the function.

Comment: @Jochen: Runtime analysis could still enable certain kinds of purity optimizations. Problem is that this would hardly be worth the huge effort it would mean to implement those for a dynamically typed, imperative language like Python.

Comment: @NiklasB. I wish I could give +2 for both answering my question and providing a lot of other insight. I come from no background at all, I'm just learning this stuff; but I now understand why declaring or deriving purity of a function would be impractical in Python, and why purely functional languages can do things that hybrid languages normally can't.

Comment: @max: Very nice conclusion :) You should play with Haskell sometime ;)

Comment: @JochenRitzel: your example reminded me that `math.sqrt` isn't a global name like I thought (whose unique value would be stored in `func.__globals__`). Rather, it's an expression that involves a global name `math` and a string literal `sqrt`. Clearly, nobody can guarantee what it evaluates to.

Comment: Unlike many compiled languages, you can safely assume that Python is *not* optimizing your code.

Comment: @3noch It does certain types of peephole optimizations in the bytecode, like constant folding. But generally of course what you say is true

Answer (score 3):

The code is not evaluated statically; the code inside the function is still calculated each time. The function object contains all the byte code which expresses the code in the function; it doesn't evaluate any of it. You could improve matters by calculating the expensive value once:

```
def g(a):
    root_a = math.sqrt(a)
    def f(b):
        return root_a * b
    return f
result = []
a = 100
func = g(a)
for b in range(1000000):
    result.append(func(b))
```

Naturally, in this trivial example, you could improve performance much more:

```
a = 100
root_a = math.sqrt(a)
result = [root_a * b for b in range(1000000)]
```

But I presume you're working with a more complex example than that where that doesn't scale?

Comment: Of course, you are exactly right, this is just a simplified example. I'm curious - is it a language requirement that it's not optimized away, or does each implementation decide what it wants to do?

Comment: @max: It's implementation-specific and you might get totally different results with something like PyPy or IronPython (not really sure about the latter, but it might profit from the .NET IL optimization). There are some things that are consistent across platforms, though: List comprehensions for example will very likely be much more efficient than building a list yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, the `timeit` module is your friend.  Try some things and see how it goes.  If you don't care about writing ugly code, this might help a little as well:

```
def g(a):
   def f(b,_local_func=math.sqrt):
      return _local_func(a)*b
```

Apparently python takes a performance penalty whenever it tries to access a "global" variable/function.  If you can make that access local, you can shave off a little time.

Comment: No problem.  The other answers are better than mine anyway.  The only thing that I recommend is to look into using `timeit` if it really is a performance critical portion of code.  `timeit` is pretty easy to use so it's definitely worth the small time investment.

Answer (score 0):

An old question and Python has moved forward quite a bit. For the above purpose it now provides [functools.partial()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```py
import math

def f(a, b):
    return math.sqrt(a) * b

a = 100
g = functools.partial(f, a)  # functools.partial(<function f at 0x103ccc860>, 100)

f(100, 3)  # 30.0
g(3)  # 30.0, with `a` bound by partial to 100
```